# Why is convert=soft not default in btrfs balance?

Tags: linux, btrfs

Enabling `soft` when seems to be all upside with no downside: `balance` will skip chunks which are already in the right place.

`man btrfs-balance` says:

> ```
>   soft
>        Takes no parameters. Only has meaning when converting between
>        profiles. When doing convert from one profile to another and soft
>        mode is on, chunks that already have the target profile are left
>        untouched. This is useful e.g. when half of the filesystem was
>        converted earlier but got cancelled.
>
>        The soft mode switch is (like every other filter) per-type. For
>        example, this means that we can convert metadata chunks the "hard"
>        way while converting data chunks selectively with soft switch.
> ```

Are there any cases in which one would **not** wish to pass `soft`?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this elsewhere in the meantime?